# Error with react app: refuses to connect to postgre DB

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, create-react-app

So my team created an a react app with node.js. I am trying to setup the project on my computer, but I have been getting the following error:

```
> project@1.0.0 start C:\Users\username\Desktop\project
> node server.js

Listening on port: 5000
GET /ping 304 2.853 ms - -
(node:11456) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
    at connection.connect.err (C:\Users\username\Desktop\project\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\postgres\connection-manager.js:170:24)
    at Connection.connectingErrorHandler (C:\Users\username\Desktop\project\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:191:14)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Socket.reportStreamError (C:\Users\username\Desktop\project\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:72:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
(node:11456) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11456) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Here is a snippet of code where the database is initialized:

```
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');
var express = require('express');

const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  username: 'root',
  password:'',
  database: 'db',
  dialect: 'postgres',
  define: {
    underscored: true,
  },
});
```

Comment: are you sure your credentials are correct? the default superuser for a postgres database is not `root` but `postgres`

Comment: It doesn't work even when I don't have username / password

Comment: That doesn't mean it won't work with the correct username/password

Comment: What would default username and password be?